# Component Missing when Nested inside of Route in React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

When nesting the `ChoosePlayer` component inside a `Route` using React Router v6,

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

    <Route path="/players">
      <Route element={<ChoosePlayer />} />
      // <--- Some dynamically generated routes here for /players/{playerName}
      // These inner routes shows a modal in addition to ChoosePlayer in the background
    </Route>

  </Routes> 
</BrowserRouter>
```

the `ChoosePlayer` component does not render when we are on the url `http://localhost:3000/players` or `http://localhost:3000/players/reacher`.

As a sanity check, `ChoosePlayer` component is rendered at `http://localhost:3000/chooseplayer` when we have

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/chooseplayer" element={<ChoosePlayer />} />
  </Routes> 
</BrowserRouter>
```

and at `http://localhost:3000/players` when `index` is added to its `Route` component, but this prevents `ChoosePlayer` from showing up at `http://localhost:3000/players/reacher`

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

    <Route path="/players">
      <Route index element={<ChoosePlayer />} />
      // <--- Some dynamically generated routes here for /players/{playerName}
      // These inner routes shows a modal in addition to ChoosePlayer in the background
    </Route>

  </Routes> 
</BrowserRouter>
```

Why is it not rendering in the first example? Is there a way to do this in React Router v6? I think this approach works in React Router v5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've gathered you want to render this `ChoosePlayer` component with the path is `"/players"` ***and also*** when on *some* `"/players/*"` path. In this case you are treating `ChoosePlayer` more as a layout component that renders a set of nested routes.

## Issue

> ```
> <BrowserRouter>
>   <Routes>
>     <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
>     <Route path="/players">
>       <Route element={<ChoosePlayer />} />
>       // <--- Some dynamically generated routes here for /players/{playerName}
>       // These inner routes shows a modal in addition to ChoosePlayer in the background
>     </Route>
>   </Routes> 
> </BrowserRouter>
> ```

The `ChoosePlayer` route is missing a path for matching and rendering.

> ```
> <BrowserRouter>
>   <Routes>
>     <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
>     <Route path="/chooseplayer" element={<ChoosePlayer />} />
>   </Routes> 
> </BrowserRouter>
> ```

`ChoosePlayer` is matched and rendered, but isn't on a `"/players/*"` route and doesn't have any nested children routes.

> ```
> <BrowserRouter>
>   <Routes>
>     <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
>     <Route path="/players">
>       <Route index element={<ChoosePlayer />} />
>       // <--- Some dynamically generated routes here for /players/{playerName}
>       // These inner routes shows a modal in addition to ChoosePlayer in the background
>     </Route>
>   </Routes> 
> </BrowserRouter>
> ```

An an index route, `ChoosePlayer` is matched and rendered when the path is *exactly* `"/players"`, but is excluded from being rendered when matching and rendering one of the other nested routes.

## Solution

I suggest moving `ChoosePlayer` up into the root `"/players"` route and render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to be rendered into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const ChoosePlayer = () => {
  //  ...any component business logic...

  return (
    <div /* any container props/styling/etc... */>
      {/* Common Choose Players UI */}
      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render into here
    </div>
  );
};
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/players" element={<ChoosePlayer />} >
      // <--- Some dynamically generated routes here for /players/{playerName}
      // These inner routes shows a modal in addition to ChoosePlayer in the background
    </Route>
  </Routes> 
</BrowserRouter>
```

You can read more about layout routes [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes).